# Criar página login para Hotel para aceder ao WIFI

Tags: aplicação-web, redes

Os hoteis normalmente partilham *WIFI*, mas é necessário entrar numa página de autenticação, eu precisava de fazer o mesmo mas tenho uma dúvida, essa página fica alocada no Router?
Obrigado

Comment: Na verdade é um servidor de autenticação(ou deveria ser).

Comment: Ou seja, deveria ter um servidor a receber do Router e a enviar o sinal?

Comment: Depende da complexidade da rede. Pode-se ter toda uma estrutura de servidor de autenticação, para que somente pessoas autorizadas e credenciadas acessem a rede, e um servidor DHCP, que vai distribuir os ips, e os roteadores vão apenas atuar como AP, apenas replicando o sinal.

Comment: sabe de algum tutorial online sobre este tema?

Comment: @SaPires veja se esses tutoriais resolvem seu problema: http://lifehacker.com/5791208/run-your-home-network-like-a-coffee-shop e https://www.raymond.cc/blog/create-a-wireless-internet-hotspot-at-home-in-10-minutes-for-free/

Comment: Pesquise também por captive portal, pode ajudar...